# Google Card Style 9-Patch with ListView - Android

Tags: android, listview, nine-patch

I am trying to use the card_background 9-patch that is extracted from the play store apk and I am having trouble getting the 9-Patch to place itself correctly. Here is an image of my emulator running this problem. I am trying to make the typical card view that is used somewhat commonly now but this is just one of the problems I cannot work out how to fix.

[image]

My 9-Patch card_background:
[image]

I am also pretty sure the 9-Patch is setup incorrectly as according to the 9-Patch tool in /sdk/tools the entire two areas that I am using are both bad patches but I don't know what that means so I hope one of you can help to fix this.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but what's wrong with it? Can we get an image of what it *should* look like, too?

Comment: @Geobits it is supposed to look like the Google Play card style thing with the grey shadow underneath. http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/nexusae0_wm_2013-03-20-20.32.51.png

Answer (score 11):

I modified your image, I think this works: [image]

Comment: This is by far the easiest and most computationally sound method of implementing Google Now style cards in a list view. Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Your 9-patch image stretches all the white/border correctly, but it has nothing but transparency at the bottom. If you want a gray shadowy area beneath it, you need to draw it there, below the white. Just make sure you don't extend the black stretch-bar down to it, or it will stretch as well.

Comment: There is a shadow area below it though as it is taken directly from the Google Play apk.

Comment: Oh, wow, I see it now. Man, that is a *very* transparent gray. They may be doing some drawable layering, but I'd try reducing the vertical stretch area up a couple pixels first. It looks like it's stretching the curved area of the card, which you definitely don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the `sdk's nine-patch editor` tool after you extract the png's from the apk and put them in their respective drawable folders. The tool can either be the one inside the /tools or, even better, the direct editor in Android Studio.

`Modify the stretch regions` for each image to your liking until it looks like an actual card. I had the same problem, until I went back and redid the stretch regions. For some reason, the png extracted from the apk didn't save the stretch regions when extracted.

You should have a shadow automatically appear from the given images, you **DO NOT** need to draw it yourself. Just make sure you don't include the corners and the shadow in the stretch region. And give a little bit of slack too.

[image: My android studio nine-patch edit of the hdpi card png]